# Minimal lambda throws exception when uploaded to AWS

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

My local dotnet version is `6.0.400` and `dotnet lambda --help` shows version `5.4.5`.

I have scaffolded a test lambda project with `dotnet new serverless.AspNetCoreMinimalAPI -n TestCalc`.

If I load this in VSCode and hit `F5` it runs just fine; Giving me the classic `localhost:5000/calculator` responses.

If I then:

1. Create a new Lambda in the AWS Console
2. Set the Function URL `Auth type` to `NONE`
3. Check `Configure cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)`
4. Set the handler to `TestCalc`
5. Set the `TestCalc.csproj` value `PublishReadyToRun` to `false`
6. Publish the `TestCalc` project locally with `dotnet publish -c Release --output=publish`
7. Zip the contents of the `\TestCalc\publish` folder
8. Upload the `publish.zip` file to the Lambda

And hit the function URL, I get this error logged to CloudWatch:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.HandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass26_0`2.<<GetHandlerWrapper>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

It appears (to me) that the function is being invoked but the AWS Lambda library is failing to receive something it expects.

How can I give it what it needs?

The generated code (plus some logging from me) is this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Add AWS Lambda support. When application is run in Lambda Kestrel is swapped out as the web server with Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer. This
// package will act as the webserver translating request and responses between the Lambda event source and ASP.NET Core.
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Welcome to running ASP.NET Core Minimal API on AWS Lambda");

app.Logger.LogInformation($"before app.Run()"); // appears in CloudWatch
app.Run();
app.Logger.LogInformation($"after app.Run()"); // does NOT appear in CloudWatch
```

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this github post](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1175) I figured I should check the options on the `LambdaEventSource` and switched it to `LambdaEventSource.HttpApi`. This solved the problem.